# How to Add the Form in Panel from another VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working with windows form VB.net. I want to display a form in the panel of other form.IN this Condition in VB.net then the code
3 form call is : main form  ,Borrower form , Camera form .
my steps are: click button in main form
->Borrower form  .show() in main' form  panel (here is ok match with requirement) , then click button in Borrower form
-> Camera form  .show() , have code in here to get variable in to Borrower  form
-> click button in Camera form  show Borrower form  .
I wanna Camera form  and Borrower form  (after get variable) have show in main' form  panel all the time .
How can I fix it. Here is my code in Import. thank you.

in main form

```
dim frmBorrower as new Form
Public Sub addForm(frm As Form)
        pnlContainer.Controls.Clear()
        frm.TopLevel = False
        frm.TopMost = True
        frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        pnlContainer.Controls.Add(frm)
        frm.Show()
    End Sub
```

in Camera form  ( get variable in formBorrer and show formBorrer in  formmain'panel )

```
Private Sub btChoose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btChoose.Click
        PictureBox2.Image.Save(Me.TextBox1.Text & ".jpg")
        'PictureBox2.Image.Save(Me.TextBox1.Text & ".jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        getcameraImage = Me.PictureBox2.Image
        Me.PictureBox2.Image.Tag = Me.TextBox1.Text & ".jpg"
        getimgname = Me.PictureBox2.Image.Tag
        CAMERA.Stop()
        Me.Close()
        frmBorrer.PictureBox1.Image = getcameraImage
        frmBorrer.txtPhoto.Text = getimgname
        frmBorrer.txt_bid.Text = getborro
        frmBorrer.txt_fname.Text = getFirstname
        frmBorrer.txt_lname.Text = getLastname
        frmBorrer.txt_mname.Text = getMiddleName
        frmBorrer.rch_address.Text = getAddress
        frmBorrer.rdio_female.Checked = getSex
        frmBorrer.txtContact.Text = getContactNo
        frmBorrer.txtCourse.Text = getCourseYear
        frmBorrer.txtPhoto.Text = getBorrowerPhoto
        Dim frmmain As formmain  'error is here , the error mess is : form main is nothing
        frmmain.addForm(frmBorrer)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why add forms to a `Panel` in the first place? It's very rare that that's a good idea. If you genuinely want to host multiple child forms inside a parent form then you probably ought to be using the MDI functionality built into WinForms. If you just want to be able to host groups of child controls in the same parent form then you should be using user controls rather than forms. You design a user control in pretty much the same way as a form but then you use it like any other control. Adding a control to a `Panel` is quite normal.

Comment: thanks your advice it help me so much , i tried to google and research lot of issue  but they did not match my requirements .if just open Borrfrm to display in mainform' panel by click action in main form then it is working , but problem is  to be able call Borrower from a lot of form such as main frm, Camera frm ... and update data . but when Borrower form (or other form) display location always  is  main form' panel () that why i think to design a control is  addForm() then can call form every where, it exactly when click in main form but  it error when call Borrower form from camera form .

Answer (score 0):

I think you should think about using MDI for this, in stead of trying to do this yourself.

anyway, in your code you are declaring a variable from a type with the same name as your variable. That won't work.

```
 Dim frmmain As frmmain
```

I suspect that `frmmain` is a type for a form ?
In that case you problaby need someting like

```
 Dim formmain As frmmain
```

as you can see, the name of the variable is different than the name of the type.
I don't know vb but this is the same in any language

But that is not the only problem in your code
When I read your code, I think you don't want to create a variable there, but use a variable that is created elsewhere.
Probably somewhere else there is created a form main like this

```
dim frmmain as new form
```

and where you do `dim frmmain as frmmain` you probably just need to remove that line of code and use the variable that was created elsewhere.

Without more code from you, it is impossible to say

Comment: thank you so much, I researched MDI did not match my requirements . my problem is can call frmBorrer every where i want such as Camera form (just not from main form by click action button) . that is why i try to to design a control is addForm()  it exactly when click in main form but it error when call Borrower form from camera form . in my code , i wanna call addForm() in  formmain then i  declaring a variable from .  I  edited exactly code that i writed but it is error . :(